# Angular: Calling a service or a function on reload / refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

When the user clicks/presses the F5 button page refresh the guard warns the user about data loss. I want to execute one function that calls a service that deletes all the data from the database that the user just created when the reload button is clicked.

ExampleComponent:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements ComponentCanDeactivate {

    @HostListener("window:beforeunload")
      canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this.user || this.workingStatus || this.engagement) {
          console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
          this.delete();
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
}
```

Delete function:

```
delete(): void {
    this.service.deleteWorkingStatus().toPromise().then(() => {
      this.workingStatus = null;
    });
    this.service.deleteEngagement().toPromise().then(() => {
      this.engagement = null;
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.service.deleteUser().toPromise().then(() => {
        this.user = null;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

This function works just fine but even if the "cancel" button was clicked the data is still being deleted.

How can I just delete the data when the reload is happening but not when the guard is showing up?

[guard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcdIG.png)

Comment: So, how do you handle the button click in the guard?

Comment: I don't, is there any way where I can handle the button click in the guard? This guard is being executed when CanDeactive is being called with window:beforeunload. And in the function, I added that it needs to warn the user if there is data in this.user or this.workingStatus or this.engagement objects, if there is any then guard warns the user, if not the page should refresh without a problem.